# SQL how to update left joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a MAssive sql query... its of a few tables i innerjoined... and now, i have to update them..
I have Noooo idea how to do that.. this is my query (thats works).
And after it is one way i tried to get the update statement to work, but... i obviously i did not succeed..

My sql query is

```
select t1.name AS DistroName,t2.name AS OriginName, t3.name AS DesktopName, t3.name AS desktoptest , t2.country, t1.status, t2.description , t5.name as oldtest, t6.name as multitest, t4.name as begintest
from alldistros t1 
LEFT join origin t2 on t1.name=t2.name
LEFT join desktop t3 on t2.name=t3.name
LEFT join beginnerdistributions t4 on t3.name=t4.name
LEFT join oldcomputers t5 on t4.name=t5.name
LEFT join multimedia t6 on t5.name=t6.name
WHERE t1.name = 'Absolute LInux'
```

Now how do i update, lets say for instance the t1.name field to "CatMan" where t1.name = 'Absolute LInux'?

i literally cant see any logical way of doing that in this particular case...

Thank you, Ruan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UPDATE alldistros SET name="CatMan" WHERE name = "Absolute Linux"
```

I think you're getting the concept of tables and queries mixed up.

Comment: but you see there are 'name' fields in more than one table in my database. 
and the name "absolute Lunux" can be in any one of the 3tables.
Thats why i joined them in the first place.

Comment: In this particular case, since all of the names are the same, you can just apply the above query six times, one for each table.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhh Thats kinda clever..... oky kwl, im gona try that, thanx. Will let you know how it went

Comment: your method worked, thank you. i just updated every table in one go. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you?

```
UPDATE alldistros
SET name = "CatMan"
from alldistros t1 
LEFT join origin t2 on t1.name=t2.name
LEFT join desktop t3 on t2.name=t3.name
LEFT join beginnerdistributions t4 on t3.name=t4.name
LEFT join oldcomputers t5 on t4.name=t5.name
LEFT join multimedia t6 on t5.name=t6.name
WHERE t1.name = 'Absolute LInux'
```

Maybe I am mis-reading the question, did you want to update all table's name column where the name is what you are looking for?

Comment: Ive tried this, but theres an error in that statement. And ive tried writing "catman" like 'catman'
But still an error